# How to add interceptor to $resource in angular

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, angular-resource

I want to intercept requests in a resource call. The purpose of my interceptor is to intercept http requests and Authorization header to all requests that are sent to server. This is my interceptor:

```
module.exports = function (authToken) {
return {
    request: function(config){
        var token = authToken.getToken();
        if(token){
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }

        console.log(config);
        return config;
    },
    response: function(response){
        return response;
    }
}
};
```

As a part of config function I am pushing authInterceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

I am also defining interceptor as a $resource parameter:

```
module.exports = function ($resource, gwService, authInterceptor) {

return $resource(gwService.getResourceUrl('/environments/:environmentId'), null,
    {
        'update': {method: 'PUT'},
        'query': {method: 'GET', interceptor: authInterceptor}
    }
);
};
```

I cannot figure out why authInterceptor is never executed. Is it possible to intercept $resource in angular or I have to use $http?

Comment: you don't need to pass interceptor in $resource

Comment: it´s still the same :) The problem is that Authorization header is never added to http request

Answer (score 0):

Now This is how i do,

When i need to have a generic Header, means a header that i want to use in each and every request then i configure my header like this

```
$http.defaults.headers.post.Authorization = "Bearer QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==";
```

But when i want an header per request ,means i should be able to decide which request would involve authorization header and which will not have headers then i do something like this.

```
 .factory('APIAuthroization', function (authToken) {
     return {
         transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
             var headers = headersGetter();
             var token = authToken.getToken();
             if (token) {
                 headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
             }
             return JSON.stringify(data);
         }
     }
 })
```

and then set this `transformRequest` to the `transformRequest` of `$resource`

```
return $resource(gwService.getResourceUrl('/environments/:environmentId'), null,
    {
        'update': {method: 'PUT'},
        'query': {method: 'GET', transformRequest: APIAuthroization.transformRequest}
    }
);
};
```

Comment: I am testing your approach. transformRequest is called but header is never changed in request. I am using angular 1.2.28 version